# Move semantics of a method chained to a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

I am new to C++ and am trying to get a grip on move semantics.  The following code is a barebones struct I wrote.  It is not the best example of software engineering by any means, but it is just for learning purposes.  It owns a resource, has the copy constructor and copy assignment operator deleted, has a move constructor and a move assignment operator defined, has a destructor, and has a single method that is supposed to return the original object:

```
struct HasAResource
{
    int* arr;

    HasAResource(int size):
        arr(new int [size])
    {}

    HasAResource(const HasAResource& other) = delete;
    HasAResource& operator=(const HasAResource& other) = delete;

    HasAResource(HasAResource&& other):
        arr(nullptr)
    {
        arr = other.arr;
        other.arr = nullptr;
    }

    HasAResource& operator=(HasAResource&& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            delete[] arr;
            arr = other.arr;
            other.arr = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~HasAResource() { delete[] arr; }

    HasAResource& doStuff()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    HasAResource x = HasAResource(42).doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

In the main function, I attempted to construct an object and call the method on it immediately.  My goal was to modify the temporary object I constructed and them move it to `x` without making any copies (so that there is only one owner of the resource).  However, the compiler gives me an error related to the deleted copy constructor.  This means that it is trying to make a copy despite my best efforts.

My questions are:

1. What exactly is happening here?  Where is the new object an rvalue or an lvalue and why?
2. How can I modify this program to achieve the desired behavior, if it is possible?

Once again, my goal is to understand *what the language is doing*, not the best software engineering practices (like using `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: `HasAResource x = (expression that evaluates to HasAResource&)` what operation did you expect this to use, and why?

Comment: Well, I'm no expert, but it seems like you're passing the temporary by reference to the constructor of the new object. That would imply a copy constructor. You could pass by value, i.e. use rvo or try to cast to an rvalue reference using std::move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal was to modify the temporary object I constructed and them move it to `x` without making any copies

`doStuff()` does not return a *temporary*, so there is no rvalue for `x` to move from. Since the return value of `doStuff()` is not an rvalue, the compiler can't call your move constructor for `x`, hence why it tries to call the copy constructor instead and thus fails due to that being `delete`'d.

In this case, you will need to use [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) explicitly to convert the returned reference into an rvalue, then the move constructor will be called as expected:

```cpp
HasAResource x = std::move(HasAResource(42).doStuff());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/NIpbzZ)

Otherwise, change `doStuff()` to return a new object by value, and let the compiler optimize away that temporary for you using [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), eg:

```cpp
static HasAResource doStuff(int size)
{
    HasAResource x(size);
    x.doStuff();
    return x;
}

HasAResource x = HasAResource::doStuff(42);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/EWKH9B)

Comment: `HasAResource&& doStuff() &&;` is another alternative